# Maximum dp/dip on android devices

Tags: android, density-independent-pixel

Since dip stands for "device independent pixels", is there a standard number of dip for every android device out there?

Example: if a hdpi device has X dp/width and Y dp/height, does a ldpi device have the same values? Namely X and Y?

If so, can anyone tell me the exact numbers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, but this is how you roughly maps actual sizes and densities to generalized sizes and densities.

[image: a busy cat]

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Comment: So what size corresponds to what device form factor? For example, which size corresponds to phones? None of those sizes are portrait...

Comment: So work with 320dp full width-portrait (MDPI)? I use this calc https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter `ldpi = 240px | mdpi = 320px | hdpi = 480px | xhdpi = 640px | xxhdpi = 960px | xxxhdpi = 1280px`